# I can't get my python code to work with crontab

Tags: python, cron

I'm having trouble getting code to work with crontab. My final goal would be to be able to scrape automatically using python and crontab. For the moment I'm trying to save data that I generate myself in a txt file. here is what I tried:

I have a test.py file on my desktop that looks like this :

```
def function():

    print('hello')
    return "hello"


function()
```

I tried this command in the teminal :

```
crontab -e
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /Users/raphael/Desktop/test.py >> Users/raphael/Desktop/test.txt
```

It is supposed to return a test.txt file with written "hello" but nothing is returned.
I don't understand why, I need your help please

Comment: are you checking the right file? theres no slash at start of output file

Comment: thanks for the answer, I added the slah and the test.txt file is created, but no data is stored inside.